# Is it possible to move selenium manager location from cache to another directory for downloading webdriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, seleniummanager

My selenium based automation framework is using selenium 4.15. It's able to download selenium-manager.exe to C:\Users\xxxx.cache\selenium\manager\0.4.15 folder. But due to firewall/proxy of my organization, it doesn't allow execution of this exe from this location and throw an error.
I manually copied it to a different directory within my C: drive and i was able to run this exe without any issues.

Question: as this process run behind the scene when the following command is executed, is it possible to copy or change the download location of selenium-manager.exe and let it run from there to download the webdriver?
`driver = new ChromeDriver((ChromeOptions) data.Options);`

I have tried downgrading selenium-java to 4.14 but that didn't help either. I tried reaching out to my security and network team but they are hesitant to provide access to an executable file.

Comment: there's a cache path and a manager path... you should be able to set system environment variables for each:  managerPath = System.getenv("SE_MANAGER_PATH");  cache-path is System.getenv("CACHE_PATH_ENV");  The selenium manager executable is extracted at run-time:  https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/trunk/java/src/org/openqa/selenium/manager/SeleniumManager.java